# Date type without time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, date, oracle10g

In Oracle 10g I got a problem when using `DATE` type in my table. I just want my `DATE` field store only `DATE` without time automatically.

There's so much solution, I know it like using `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` or `TRUNC` but I faced that I'm using so much procedures to insert or update data and have no time to update all of them.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: personally i still use the date type and reset the time to 0.

Comment: @ericosg how can you reset the time to 0?

Comment: i think Rob van Wijk answered it quite well

Comment: I think this problem needs to be elaborated upon. It becomes a real problem not to have a `JUST_DATE` datatype when you want to establish a PK on the `DATE` column in question. If you want your table to contain only one entry per date, then you either have to ensure that the data is clean before you `INSERT` (i.e. You have to program it into your API), or you need to apply a constraint to your column, as described by @Rob-van-wijk in his (first) point 2.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The best solution would be to:

1. remove all times from your DATE column (`update yourtable set yourdatecolumn = trunc(yourdatecolumn)`)
2. ensure that all future dates contain no time part by placing a check constraint on the column by using `check (yourdatecolumn = trunc(yourdatecolumn))`
3. adjust all your INSERT and UPDATE statements or -if you're lucky- adjust your API, to only insert TRUNCed dates.

The easiest solution would be to:

1. (Optionally) remove all times from your DATE column.
2. Create a before row insert or update database trigger that sets `:new.yourdatecolumn := trunc(:new.yourdatecolumn);`

Comment: Thanks so much, the best solution for me is: update all DATE column first then add trigger before insert a row :)

Comment: Be aware that when some versions add the check constraint into the execution plan (for example if you said "where yourdatecolumn = ...") they can calculate an incorrectly small cardinality estimate as a result. I think it was 10.1

Comment: Is there no "in-built" datatype in Oracle that stores only date (without time and time zone, etc) ?

Comment: No, a DATE column with a check constraint is what comes closest.

Answer (score -6):

i use like this

insert : `Insert into table (name_date) values(to_date(current_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'));`
update : `update table set name_date=to_date(current_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') where id=1;`

that's all...