# Oracle. Inserting into the DATE field gives different results in different environments

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss

**Hello**

I have:

- database Oracle 19
- Field in oracle with type - DATE
- Application with: Jboss, EJB, Hibernate

When my application inserts data into the database, I get two different results:

Sql query which i used for collection data:

```
SELECT ID, KEY, TO_CHAR(STATUS_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATE_WITH_TIME FROM DATA dt;
```

- Production: In field DATE_WITH_TIME i always get right date but wrong time - 2023-03-20 00:00:00
- Test: In field DATE_WITH_TIME i get 2023-03-20 18:20:23 - get current date-time

Settings for test and production is identical - versions of database/application/dependencies, equals field types etc. At the same time insertions to another tables on production works properly.

**Question:**
What factor in two environments can impose such a change on the behavior when i inserting data in field DATE?
Maybe hidden setting in Oracle or Jboss.

**UPD1:**
I'm working with legacy and I know it needs to be refactored, but now I want to know why this solution worked differently for prod and test env.

Additional information:

- setting data to field - `setDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()))` -
- NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD.MM.RR -> for Production and Test
- Entity field type:

```
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name="DATE")
  private Date date;
```

Comment: The values in the two database are just different. What is your question?

Comment: It depends how you insert the data really - what data types you're using, how you supply/bind values, etc. The DB session environment might matter if you're passing strings but you'd probably see errors from format mismatches rather than truncation.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] including the Java code where you insert the data. There are multiple possible causes including whether you insert dates as bind variables with the data types `java.sql.Date` (which has no time component), `java.sql.Timestamp` (which does have a time component and matches Oracle's `DATE` data type), or as a string (which will rely on an implicit conversion in the database and then the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter would be used). If you don't share any code then we cannot comment and can only guess.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232260/temporaltemporaltype-date-with-oracle-12 (i.e. different JDBC drivers have different behaviours)

Comment: @MT0 Interesting, thanks! But we are using Oracle version 19, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: @СергейКирюшин The problem would arise from the JDBC driver version and not the RDBMS version - for example: the [JDBC driver downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) lists two different drivers OJDBC8 and OJDBC10 for Oracle 19c (but also states that OJDBC11 works with Oracle 19c) so your test and production database could be running the same databases, codebase and settings and have different OJDBC drivers.