# Setting up a YYYY only field in Oracle Table?

Tags: database, oracle, date, database-design, plsql

I am attempting to setup what will be a simple history table in my DB with the following field setup:

```
TABLE_ID
RELATED_ENTITY_ID
CALENDAR_YEAR
CREATED_DATE
CREATED_BY
```

What I can't seem to figure out (for certain) is how to setup the [CALENDAR_YEAR] DATE type field to contain ONLY the year value 'YYYY' and the [CREATED_DATE] DATE type field as ONLY the date (no time value). Can anyone more experienced weigh in on this?

This is a new table, but I also have some other table' fields declared as DATE which I need to change to only contain the date and no time. I've read a lot in the oracle documentation about using TRUNC() to return the Data specifically as xyz when querying, but if possible I would like to store the data directly as desired.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date type without time in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429276/date-type-without-time-in-oracle)

Comment: You could use an integer for the year only field.  You could use the trunc() function when you insert or update a date field.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I read about that but couldn't gather fully if the INSERT would allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either enforce your requirements with constraints, which will prevent invalid data from being entered or you can use a trigger to truncate the inserted and/or updated data to the desired values.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, CALENDAR_YEAR DATE NOT NULL 
, CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
, CREATED_BY NUMBER NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT TABLE2_PK PRIMARY KEY ( TABLE_ID ) ENABLE
, CONSTRAINT TABLE2_CHK1 CHECK (CALENDAR_YEAR = TRUNC(CALENDAR_YEAR,'year')) ENABLE
, CONSTRAINT TABLE2_CHK2 CHECK (CREATED_DATE = TRUNC(CREATED_DATE)) ENABLE
);
```

If you don't include TABLE2_CHK1 and TABLE2_CHK2 then the following trigger will truncate any inserted or updated values as needed:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TABLE2_BIU_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CALENDAR_YEAR,CREATED_DATE ON TABLE2 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
      :NEW.TABLE_ID := TABLE2_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    WHEN UPDATING THEN
      IF :NEW.TABLE_ID != :OLD.TABLE_ID THEN
        :NEW.TABLE_ID := :OLD.TABLE_ID;
      END IF;
  END CASE;

  :NEW.CREATED_DATE := trunc(:NEW.CREATED_DATE);
  :NEW.CALENDAR_YEAR := trunc(:NEW.CALENDAR_YEAR,'YEAR');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sentinel. On the Trigger example you've provided, how do I specify the trigger setup both for what you've given and also (at the same time) setting the TABLE_ID to the next sequence value? Here is one of my current triggers (ex): DROP TRIGGER SCHEMA.TABLE1_TRG;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TABLE1_TRG
BEFORE INSERT
ON schema.TABLE1
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- For Toad:  Highlight column ID
  :new.table_ID := TABLE1_SEQ.nextval;
END TABLE1_TRG;

Comment: I've updated my code above to include sequence values, however, it's perfectly acceptable to have more than one trigger on a table, such as my original trigger that didn't handle the sequence numbers, and your insert only trigger for taking care of the sequence number.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this. The Truncation appears to still be returning a DATETIME value, hence I am always getting my DATE + 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: Correction, I was trying only the Trigger version with a modification for IS NOT NULL check. Adding the Truncation as a CONSTRAINT appears to be working for all fields where I only wish to save the DATE itself.

Comment: DATE + 12:00 AM is midnight. In 24hour time that 00:00.  Oracle Date and TimeStamp data types always have a time component, but midnight is usually treated as having no time component.  Similarly truncating to the year yields a date of 1-Jan-2015 with the time component zeroed out to midnight.