# Is there a way to differentiate in Oracle/JDBC between DATE and TIMESTAMP?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java application where the user builds their SQL `select` statement on the screen. Once they enter the `select`, I analyze with JDBC the column types.

For Oracle, the JDBC equivalent of type DATE is `java.sql.Types.Timestamp`, as DATE includes the time.

The problem is that I need to format the result set depending on the column type. If it's DATE, I need to format the value `YYYY-MM-DD`. If it's TIMESTAMP, I need to format the value `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

What I need is to differentiate in JDBC between DATE and TIMESTAMP results. Is there a way to achieve this?

Sample code:

```
        String sql = "select date_col, timestamp_col from some_table";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int count = meta.getColumnCount();

        for (int i=1;i <= count;i++) {
            int type = meta.getColumnType(i);
            System.out.println(type);
        }
```

This prints twice 93, which is `java.sql.Types.Timestamp`.

```
CREATE TABLE "DB1"."SOME_TABLE" 
   ("SOMENUM" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "DATE_COL" DATE, 
    "TIMESTAMP_COL" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ACCOUNT" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "BALANCE" FLOAT(126))
```

Note: I'm running this on Wildfly 14

I tried to cast the sql Connection to OracleConnection (to get the `oracle.sql` types) and Wildfly throws:

> org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast
>   to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date type without time in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429276/date-type-without-time-in-oracle)

Comment: @Mick The answers to the question you mention talk about how to insert a DATE column without time. What I need is to differentiate in JDBC between DATE and TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Hmm.. actually, according to [the specs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28905) SQL DATE in Oracle maps to [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), which doesn't include any time information. Could you share some code to highlight your exact problem?

Comment: added sample code

Comment: Could you share the DDL for `some_table`?

Comment: Added the CREATE TABLE

Comment: I don't have an Oracle DB to try this on, but `ResultSetMetaData` has `getSchemaName`, `getTableName` and `getColumnName` methods. Can you use these to look up info in the metadata views (I think `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` is the appropriate one in Oracle), and use the JDBC type as a fallback?

Comment: you mean to get the type from the column name? I cannot do that as a column may be a function.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the specs link I added above. The type used is actually Oracle-specific, `oracle.sql.Date`. Could you try to use Oracle-specific types by type-casting the metadata object into [`OracleDatabaseMetaData`](https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html)?

Comment: In Oracle, `DATE` **is** equivalent to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP` type as it as a time component, so that is why JDBC reports it as a `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: What does the 'getColumnTypeName(int column)' method return?

Comment: @JAlexey great idea, they return DATE and TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Casting is the wrong way to get a handle to the `OracleConnection`  object.  Instead: `oracleConn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn.getUnderlyingConnection();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ResultSetMetdata#getColumnTypeName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnTypeName-int-) to get actual DB type name

> Retrieves the designated column's database-specific type name.
>
> Return type name used by the database. If the column type is a user-defined type, then a fully-qualified type name is returned.